# how to send a html table through to mvc action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, itext

What I am attempting is to have a button on a screen ontop of a table which when clicked on downloads a pdf with the content of the table the user sees.

This is how I create the PDF and what the Action method looks like...

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(string content)
{
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream);
    document.Open();
    document.Add(new Paragraph(content));
    document.Close();

    byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
    outputStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
    outputStream.Position = 0;

    //Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf"); 
    //return File(byteInfo, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    return File(outputStream, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

This is the table im trying to print...

```
<table class="donationTable statementTable">
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th> <th>Fees</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
         Jan
     </td>
     <td>
         $5
     </td>
   </tr>    
</table>

<a href = "@Url.Action("DownloadPdf", "Home", new { content = "" })">Download</a>
```

Comment: How is this table generated? Are you using some server side control? What library do you intend to use in order to create a PDF file because as we all know .NET has no such capability built-in.

Comment: Is the table hardcoded (which is what you have shown us) or does it contain dynamic data? Also I've added the `itextsharp` tag to your question as apparently that's the framework you are using to generate PDF.

Comment: Several of the PDF generator libraries can create a PDF from an URL.

Comment: contains dynamic content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3) which illustrates a nice way to convert Razor views into PDF using iTextsharp. The idea is that you would put this table into a partial and then:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    return this.ViewPdf("My table", "_SomePartial", model);
}
```

`ViewPdf` is an extension method that executes the Razor view and retrieves its rendered output in a string which is then fed to iTextsharp and converted into PDF.

Now you could have an anchor on your page pointing to this action which would allow th user to download the PDF:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export table as Pdf", "DownloadPdf", null, new { target = "_blank" })
```

This being said you should be aware that iTextsharp has not been designed for converting HTML into PDF and has very limited support for it. If you have some fancy CSS rules in your HTML table they won't be translated.

Comment: As shown in my answer: `return this.ViewPdf("My table", "_SomePartial", model);`. But you must derive from `PdfViewController` instead of `Controller` because the `ViewPdf` method is defined there. Just download the sample project from the CodeProject article and you can start playing with.